# Can you set the timezone with trigger.io calendar

Tags: calendar, timezone, trigger.io

I am using the add to calendar function of trigger.io as part of my app. I was wondering if there is any way to set the calendar time-zone so items will not just default to the users' time-zone.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see anything in the trigger.io documentation about time zones, but it appears to support JavaScript.

You will likely need a JavaScript time zone library such as one of those that I listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15171030/634824).